# Talmudic sages of Davidic descent

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara, rabbis, king-david, genealogy

Which (individual) sages of Talmud were said to be traced back to King David? IIRC, R. Hillel was one (?). Are there others? Sources are welcome.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_Bustanai%2C_The_Tale_of_Rabbi_Bustanai?vhe=Otzar_Midrashim,_New_York,_1915&lang=he

Comment: IIRC, we can see from many examples, that both sides count (fraternal or maternal), like in Pinchas Ben Elazar (was called בן פוטיפרע).

Comment: I don't  have a source off hand but they say Rashi descended from King David through R'' Yochanan HaSandlar.

Comment: I don't  have a source off hand but they say Rashi descended from King David through R'' Yochanan HaSandlar.

Answer (score 5):

The Rashei Galusa in Bavel were descended from David, and we know that some of them were among the Amoraim. They include [the earlier Rav Huna](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%90) (a contemporary of R' Yehudah Hanassi, and possibly a teacher of Shmuel), [Mar Ukva](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A8_%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%91%D7%90), and [Rav Huna brei dR' Nosson](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%91_%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F). Also R' Nosson (the Av Beis Din in the time of Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel II) was a son of the Reish Galusa (see [Horios 13b](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=28&daf=13b&format=pdf) and the elucidation of it cited in note ה [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=1374#p=90)).

R' Sherira Gaon also [identifies](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=1374#p=160) the better-known Rav Huna (disciple and successor of Rav) as מבי נשיאה, from the family of the Nasi (Reish Galusa), which might also mark him as a descendant of David (although not necessarily: it could just mean that he was related to them by marriage, as was Rav Nachman).

Answer (score 3):

[Ketubot 62b](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.62b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) says that **Rav Yehuda HaNasi** was a descendent of King David. This most likely means his father [**Rav Shimon ben Gamliel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simeon_ben_Gamaliel_II) (II) was as well.

The Wikipedia entry for [Hillel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_the_Elder) says he also was a descendant of King David:

> According to the "Iggeret of **Rav Sherira Gaon**" (a comprehensive history of the composition of the Talmud from the 10th century), Hillel descended from the Tribe of Benjamin on his father's side, and from the family of David on his mother's side.

Comment: Hillel, Rabban Shim'on ben Gamli'el and Rabbi Yehuda Hannasi were all from the same line. I didn't look at Rav Sherira's letter inside but I'm guessing his source is from [Bereshit Rabba 33:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bereishit_Rabbah.33.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he): Rabbi says וְאִין סָלֵיק רַב הוּנָא רֵישׁ גָּלוּתָא לְהָכָא, אֲנָא קָאֵים לִי מִן קֳדָמוֹהִי, לָמָּה דְּהוּא מִן יְהוּדָה וַאֲנָא מִן בִּנְיָמִין, וְהוּא מִן דִּכְרַיָא דִּיהוּדָה וַאֲנָא מִן נֻקְבְתָא

Comment: @ba could be- will try to see if I can find it in the letter later and if so will edit it in

Comment: *"This most likely means"* - this doesn't. As I commented above we can conclude that if the Gemmorah mentions R"Y and not his father R'Shimon, R"Y was related by his maternal line. THis is very suspicious when any source mentions only one person and not all of his descendants (Hilel and not R"G, R"Y etc).

Comment: @AlBerko There are other sources too (at least one). [מגילת יוחסין מצאו בירושלם וכתוב בה הלל מן דדוד](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%AA%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%93_%D7%91)

Comment: @ba Right, those are with all the contradicting scrolls they have found. What does it mean הילל מן דדוד? SHouldn't it say מן דוד? How come Bavli didn't know of that?

Comment: @AlBerko 1. What contradictions? 2. מן דדוד is the Aramaic equivalent of משל דוד. and 3. I assume the Bavli did know if since (as quoted by alicht's answer) it says Rabbi was descended from David

Comment: @ba the previous passages deal with contradicting Torah scrolls that were "unexpectedly" found. The Gemmorah continues, there was another scroll of genealogy. 3. Is *that* a contradiction? Since Rabbi descended from Hillel?